# Windows 8.1 64-Bit: Power Schemes gone

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, windows-8.1, powercfg

So I just ran powercfg /restoredefaultschemes because Windows 8.1 would not let me create new power schemes properly. The result was that suddenly all power schemes were gone.
It looks like this (with a few annotations):

[image]

<strike>Unless anyone knows how to "properly" restore them, I'd like to request these registry keys:</strike>

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\

It should be coming from a desktop PC with an Intel processor, because that is the most likely to work. If you are sure that the processor doesn't matter (I'm not), please send me your keys as well.

Of course, all other solutions are very welcome, too

Comment: Because it won't let me answer my question yet, I comment:

This turns out to be registry permission problem.
The permissions seemingly aren't set in the correct way which powercfg & co. need them.
I was able to restore the defaults by making those permissions very lenient, then running powercfg /restoredefaultschemes. After that I changed them back.